# Optimized way of modifying a column based on another column of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, optimization

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>  Time      level  value  a_flag  a_rank  b_flag  b_rank  c_flag  c_rank  d_flag  d_rank  e_flag  e_rank
0   2017-04-01  State   NY  1   44  1   96  1   40  1   88  0   81
1   2017-05-01  State   NY  0   42  0   55  1   92  1   82  0   38
2   2017-06-01  State   NY  1   11  0   7   1   35  0   70  1   61
3   2017-07-01  State   NY  1   12  1   80  1   83  1   47  1   44
4   2017-08-01  State   NY  1   63  1   48  0   61  0   5   0   20
5   2017-09-01  State   NY  1   56  1   92  0   55  0   45  1   17
```

I'd like to replace all the values of columns with `_rank` as `NaN` if it's corresponding flag is zero.To get something like this:

```
>>  Time    level   value   a_flag  a_rank  b_flag  b_rank  c_flag  c_rank  d_flag  d_rank  e_flag  e_rank
0   2017-04-01  State   NY  1   44.0    1   96.0    1   40.0    1   88.0    0   NaN
1   2017-05-01  State   NY  0   NaN     0   NaN     1   92.0    1   82.0    0   NaN
2   2017-06-01  State   NY  1   11.0    0   NaN     1   35.0    0   NaN     1   61.0
3   2017-07-01  State   NY  1   12.0    1   80.0    1   83.0    1   47.0    1   44.0
4   2017-08-01  State   NY  1   63.0    1   48.0    0   NaN     0   NaN     0   NaN
5   2017-09-01  State   NY  1   56.0    1   92.0    0   NaN     0   NaN     1   17.0
```

Which is fairly simple. This is my approach for the same:

```
for k in variables:
    dt[k+'_rank'] = np.where(dt[k+'_flag']==0,np.nan,dt[k+'_rank'])
```

Although this works fine for a smaller dataset, it takes a significant amount of time for processing a dataframe with very high number of columns and entries. So is there a optimized way of achieving the same without iteration?

P.S. There are other payloads apart from `_rank` and `_flag` in the data.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) to filter the columns that ends with `_flag`, then use `rstrip` to strip the `flag` label and add `rank` label to get the corresponding column names with `rank` label, then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to fill the `NaN` values in the columns containing `_rank` depending upon the condition when the corresponding values in `flag` columns is `0`:

```
flags = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_flag')]
ranks = flags.str.rstrip('flag') + 'rank'

df[ranks] = np.where(df[flags].eq(0), np.nan, df[ranks])
```

OR, it is also possible to use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df[ranks] = df[ranks].mask(df[flags].eq(0).to_numpy())
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

         Time  level value  a_flag  a_rank  b_flag  b_rank  c_flag  c_rank  d_flag  d_rank  e_flag  e_rank
0  2017-04-01  State    NY       1    44.0       1    96.0       1    40.0       1    88.0       0     NaN
1  2017-05-01  State    NY       0     NaN       0     NaN       1    92.0       1    82.0       0     NaN
2  2017-06-01  State    NY       1    11.0       0     NaN       1    35.0       0     NaN       1    61.0
3  2017-07-01  State    NY       1    12.0       1    80.0       1    83.0       1    47.0       1    44.0
4  2017-08-01  State    NY       1    63.0       1    48.0       0     NaN       0     NaN       0     NaN
5  2017-09-01  State    NY       1    56.0       1    92.0       0     NaN       0     NaN       1    17.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This method looks much cleaner than mine. But it's slower than the iteration method I'm using. I tried both of your methods.

Comment: Hmm.. What is the `variables` identifier you are using in the code you provided?

Comment: In the minimum reproducible example, I used `'a' to 'e'`. But In my actual data, those are the KPIs I'm working with. There are about 100 such KPIs.

Comment: @LazyCoder i did the performance check, and simple iteration over the all the variables while using np.where seems fast here..

Comment: @LazyCoder Using the `mask` method, you will get nearly the same performance as your method on the larger dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Shubham Sharma. Will keep that in mind:)